# React: Disable minification for a given library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, minify, react-native-xml2js

I am in the process of testing the release build of a react native app and found that the minification process is breaking the [xml parser library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-xml2js). In this case, there is a `[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dc]`, which I found out by diving through the minified bundle and logging, to be related to the above referenced library.

Is there a way to disable minification only for this library?

Also, would this be the best approach to tackle this kinds of minification problems?

Answer (score 0):

> **Disable minification for React App**

**What is the current behavior?**

When bundling production builds for React Native, names are mangled by default. This can break code (if it relies on `Function.name`) and the issue is kinda hard to track down (especially if the code accessing `Function.name` is deep into your dependency tree).

**What is the expected behavior?**

There should be at least an option to disable mangling, but I believe ideally it should be opt-in rather than opt-out. (Since it can break code in unpredictable ways)

For now relying on manually patching `minify.js`

**Solved by disabling mangling:**

Prevent `UglifyJS` from changing function argument names.

According to the documentation you can use `mangle` options to do that:

`mangle` (default `true`) — pass `false` to skip mangling names, or pass an object to specify mangling options.

**Object options:**

- `except` - pass an `Array` of identifiers that should be excluded from mangling
- `toplevel` — mangle names declared in the toplevel scope (disabled by default).
- `eval` — mangle names visible in scopes where eval or with are used (disabled by default).
- `keep_fnames` - default `false`. Pass `true` to not mangle function names. Useful for code relying on `Function.prototype.name`.

in `node_modules/metro-bundler/src/JSTransformer/worker/minify.js`

```
function minify(filename, code, sourceMap) {
        const minifyResult = uglify.minify(code, {
            fromString: true,
            inSourceMap: sourceMap,
            outSourceMap: true,
            mangle: false, // ADD THIS LINE
            output: {
              ascii_only: true,
              screw_ie8: true,
            },
        });
 })
```

**OR**

May be your issue is due to the combination of running **webpack** `-p` and using **Uglify Plugin**.

Try omitting `-p` when running build and use uglify plugin, might this fix your issue.